# Equality of random variables via quotients

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X,Y$ be $[0,\infty)$-valued random variables (defined on the same probability space) with the property that $\mathbb{E}[X/Y]\leq 1$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y/X]\leq 1$. Then $X=Y$ a.s. Does someone know how to prove this?

Comment: Hint: Consider $$E\left(\left(\sqrt{\frac{X}Y}-\sqrt{\frac{Y}X}\right)^2\right).$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!